# Adding node in Account settings tree of Thunderbirds account settings dialogue

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am developing a Thunderbird add-on in which I want to add a node to every mail account in the account manager (opens when the user clicks on Tools->Account Settings). This node should show a panel with additional settings for the account.

I have seen that the tree in this dialog is not using XUL but JavaScript instead. So i did some changes to the JavaScript file but if tomorrow a new version comes out then their will be issues with my add-on. So I need to add the node as a XUL overlay but this doesn't see possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use XUL overlays to overlay content that is built dynamically. But fortunately, the account manager is explicitly extensible. There is even [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsIMsgAccountManagerExtension/Building_an_Account_Manager_Extension) covering your exact case. In short, you need to create an XPCOM component and register it in `mailnews-accountmanager-extensions` category. The account manager will then load your component and call `showPanel()` method for each account to determine whether you want your panel to be displayed for this account. You need to set `chromePackageName` and `name` properties appropriately, the panel will be loaded from chrome://*chromePackageName*/content/am-*name*.xul and panel name from chrome://*chromePackageName*/locale/am-*name*.properties. Please note that starting with Thunderbird 4 XPCOM components [need to be registered in `chrome.manifest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0#JavaScript_components).

Comment: Thank you  Wladimir palant for your ans,  i will try these things.

Comment: HI Wladimir Palant

I am not getting how to implement what you have suggested .

Can i get the name of any plugin which does the same . 


Thanking You,

Rohit Jankar

Comment: @Rohit: [DSN Settings](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dsn-settings/) add-on uses this approach, it is pretty much an account manager panel and nothing else. Its XPCOM component is outdated however, see [XPCOM changes in Gecko 2.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0#JavaScript_components) for explanation of required adjustments.

Comment: @Rohit: [Enigmail](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/enigmail/) is another one but it is more complicated. On the bright side, its XPCOM component (`components/enigprefs-service.js`) is current and works with Thunderbird 6.

Comment: Hi Wladimir Palant  i got how to add the panel in account settings , i have one more question i want to add node it the account is of gmail i.e a@gmail.com will have node as "my settings " but b@yahoo.com will not have this node can you give me some idea how to do it.

Comment: @Rohit: That's what the `showPanel()` method is for - to choose in which accounts you want to show your panel.

Comment: Hi Wladimir i have found other problem that , suppose i have two accounts a@gmail.com and other as b@gmail.com ok if i click on node mysetting of a@gmail.com and then directly clicking my setting node of b@gmail.com so it is not calling onLoad() method it directly calling prinit(). i want it should call onload() for every time